# .NET Core Upgrading

Tags: .net-core, upgrade

I have a API that is actively being developed, running on .net core 2.1. Is the idea with .NET Core to constantly be updating my project/code to the latest version of .NET Core?

Now I see that 2.2 is stable. Should I target that, and then when 3.0 is here change to target that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's partly a matter of preference and necessity.

If you prefer to stay current and there are no breaking changes, an upgrade is advisable because you have access to new APIs, features, and performance improvements.

If upgrading would break your code due to a breaking change in an API or behavior, or upgrading adds significant maintenance issues to your project, then don't upgrade (at least until you adapt/change your code to deal with the breaking change).

Comment: Thanks that's kinda what I thought. At the moment my API project is small so any breaking changes can be quickly modified, and then once I have the project completed I wouldnt have that necessity necessarily to keep the project up to date with the latest version.